# Cant pass data from Modal Class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hy guys
I have modal class file called: orderdetails.dart where this is the code:

```
class OrderDetails {
  final shipmentNumber = "26";
}
```

I need to pass the shipmentNumber data to the widget below as a Text so

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final OrderDetails orderDetails;

  const MainPage({Key key, this.orderDetails}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  OrderDetails orderDetails;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // setState is not needed in initState
    orderDetails = OrderDetails();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

       
        Container(
          height: 1000,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: int.parse(widget.orderDetails.shipmentNumber),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, int) {
              return Card(
                color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                elevation: 15,
                child: Container(
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        widget.orderDetails.shipmentNumber,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent),
                      ),
                      Card(
                        color: Color(0xfffeaf0d),
                        child: Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.local_shipping,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 25,
                            )),
                      ),
```

but it returns NotSuchMethodError the getter shipmentNumber was called on Null
there is a way to call this method from this file?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `widget.orderDetails.shipmentNumber` which is null, you are setting state's field with `orderDetails = OrderDetails();`

Try `this.orderDetails.shipmentNumber` or add this field to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `OrderDetails()` as argument for `orderDetails` parameter while you calling **MainPage** class constructor and remove `orderDetails` field from **_MainPageState** class.

This is how you should call your **MainPage** class constructor.

```
MainPage(orderDetails: OrderDetails(),)
```